# Simple data manipulation: in Entity Model or Business layer?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, entity-model, business-layer

I'm working on an asp.net MVC application that implements the traditional Data/ Business/Presentation layered approach.

One of my entity models (representing a person) contains address/contact information including a field for "State".  My data source (which I have little control over) provides state values in full-text (Ex: "California" vs "CA", "Florida" vs "FL", etc).

I created a static helper class that we intend to use to transform the full-text values to their abbreviations.

My question is, where should this helper class be referenced and where should the transformation take place?

I see the following options:

- Use an accessor in the model that references this static class and performs the transformation on get.  Something along the lines of:

> ```
> public string State
>     {
>         get
>         {
>             return StateConverter.Abbreviate(_state);
>         }
>     }
> ```

- perform the conversion in the business layer whenever this entity model used
- Perform the conversion in the presentation layer whenever this value is displayed

I like the simplicity of having this take place in the actual model (via get accessor), but this smells a tiny bit like business logic.  The other options mean that I will have to convert this in many places (duplicating logic, traversing through people lists, etc).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is okay to put it inside your model since it is just a computed field. Moreover your Abbreviate(...) method doesn't even depend on any data outside your model. Your right to put it there.

Comment: That makes sense.  Which brings up another question.  Right now I have all models in it's own project in my overall solution.  I also have another project just for framework/helper classes.    I have no other external references in my EntityModel project.  Would adding a reference to my helper project be considered acceptable?

Comment: It's acceptable,  since your helper/ infrastructure layer deals with cross-cutting concerns.  You are allowed to reference it in any tier of your app.